# Export some part of barcode string GS1-128

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

On package box I have barcode **(01)18777777777777(15)241129(10)L3333333(90)02** after scan with devices get
01**18777777777777**15**241129**10**L3333333**F90**02**

In database I have small table barcode_settings

| CODE | NAME | SIZE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | GTIN | 14 |
| 10 | LOT | -1 is variable length end is character F |
| 15 | Best Before Date (YYMMDD) | 6 |
| 90 | Total | 2 |

Is it possible get some like this:

my_func with two parameters  **P_STRING** and **P_CODE**

select my_func('01187777777777771524112910L3333333F9002','01') from dual;
**18777777777777**

select my_func('01187777777777771524112910L3333333F9002','10') from dual;
**L3333333**

select my_func('01187777777777771524112910L3333333F9002','15') from dual;
**241129**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's possible, but with some restrictions, e.g.

- barcode has to **always** have the same format because - if it doesn't - there's no way to distinguish which e.g. `01` is which. Your original (before you changed it) sample barcode illustrates that:

  ```
  01180120708010531524112910L2238415F9002
  --  --
  two 01 values; which of them is supposed to represent CODE value?
  ```
- codes have to follow one after exactly as in that example: 01, 15, 10, 90; otherwise, you can't properly calculate lengths

---

```
SQL> create or replace function f_bc(par_string in varchar2, par_code in varchar2)
  2  return varchar2 is
  3    l_len_01 number;
  4    l_len_10 number;
  5    l_len_15 number;
  6    l_len_90 number;
  7    --
  8    l_01 varchar2(20);
  9    l_10 varchar2(20);
 10    l_15 varchar2(20);
 11    l_90 varchar2(20);
 12    retval varchar2(20);
 13  begin
 14    select csize into l_len_01 from barcode_settings where code = '01';
 15    select csize into l_len_10 from barcode_settings where code = '10';
 16    select csize into l_len_15 from barcode_settings where code = '15';
 17    select csize into l_len_90 from barcode_settings where code = '90';
 18
 19    l_01 := substr(par_string, 3, l_len_01);
 20    l_15 := substr(par_string, 2 + l_len_01 + 2 + 1, l_len_15);
 21    l_10 := substr(par_string,
 22                   2 + l_len_01 + 2 + l_len_15 + 2 + 1,
 23                   length(par_string) - (2 + l_len_01 + 2 + l_len_15 + 2 + 1 + 2 + l_len_90));
 24    l_90 := substr(par_string, -2);
 25
 26    retval := case when par_code = '01' then l_01
 27                   when par_code = '15' then l_15
 28                   when par_Code = '10' then l_10
 29                   when par_code = '90' then l_90
 30              end;
 31    return retval;
 32  end;
 33  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> with test (barcode) as
  2    (select '01180120708010531524112910L2238415F9002' from dual)
  3  select f_bc(barcode, '01') v_01,
  4         f_bc(barcode, '15') v_15,
  5         f_bc(barcode, '10') v_10,
  6         f_bc(barcode, '90') v_90
  7  from test;

V_01            V_15   V_10       V_90
--------------- ------ ---------- -----
18012070801053  241129 L2238415   02

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the other answer, If you have the **fixed length string between your special codes** (`10,15,01..`) then you can use the simple solution using `SUBSTR` and fixed starting point and length for each code separately as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_FUNC (
    P_STRING IN VARCHAR2,
    P_CODE   IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
V_OUT_STRING VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    SELECT SUBSTR(P_STRING, 
                  DECODE(P_CODE, '01', 3, '10', 27, '15', 19), 
                  DECODE(P_CODE, '01', 14, '10', 8, '15', 6))
      INTO V_OUT_STRING FROM DUAL;
RETURN V_OUT_STRING;
END MY_FUNC;
/
```

Now, You can call your function as follows:

```
SELECT MY_FUNC('01187777777777771524112910L3333333F9002','01') AS STR_01,
       MY_FUNC('01187777777777771524112910L3333333F9002','10') AS STR_10,
       MY_FUNC('01187777777777771524112910L3333333F9002','15') AS STR_15
FROM DUAL;

STR_01               STR_10               STR_15              
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
18777777777777       L3333333             241129
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, one of the columns to be extracted is of variable length (LOT). If that is the only one then we could calculate its position and length within the barcode pattern. Also there is a way to make the results conducted by your barcode_settings table making it more dynamic for possible barcode structure changes in future.
First some sample data:

```sql
WITH    -- S a m p l e    D a t a :
    barcode_settings AS
        ( Select '01' "CODE",   'GTIN' "A_NAME",    '14' "A_SIZE" From Dual Union All
          Select '10',  'LOT',  '-1 is variable length end is character F' From Dual Union All
          Select '15',  'Best Before Date (YYMMDD)',    '6' From Dual Union All
          Select '90',  'Total', '2' From Dual
        ),
    bc (ID, CODE) AS
        ( Select 1, '01187777777777771524112910L3333333F9002' From Dual Union All
          Select 2, '01181234445678901524070310L1234F9001' From Dual Union All
          Select 3, '01180009998887771524123110L1122334455F9003' From Dual 
        ),
```

Next, create a cte (cols) to get the lenghts of columns you want to extract along with the lenghts of those in between that you don't need (A, B, C, D) and calculate total length taking size of 0 for variable length column LOT.

```sql
  cols AS
    ( Select    2 "A", 
                Max(Case When CODE = '01' Then To_Number(A_SIZE) End) "GTIN_LEN",
                2 "B",
                Max(Case When CODE = '15' Then To_Number(A_SIZE) End) "A_DATE_LEN",
                2 "C",
                Max(Case When CODE = '10' Then 0 End) "LOT_LEN",
                3 "D",
                Max(Case When CODE = '90' Then To_Number(A_SIZE) End) "TOTAL_LEN",
                --
                Max(Case When CODE = '01' Then To_Number(A_SIZE) End) + 
                Max(Case When CODE = '15' Then To_Number(A_SIZE) End) + 
                Max(Case When CODE = '90' Then To_Number(A_SIZE) End) + 9 "LEN"
        From    barcode_settings 
    )
```

Using above data with SubStr() function you can get the expected result with one variable length column (LOT)....

```sql
--  M a i n    S Q L :
Select  bc.ID,  
        SubStr(bc.CODE, c.A + 1, GTIN_LEN) "GTIN", 
        Substr(bc.CODE, c.A + c.GTIN_LEN + c.B + 1, A_DATE_LEN) "A_DATE",
        SubStr(bc.CODE, c.A + c.GTIN_LEN + c.B + A_DATE_LEN + c.C + 1, (Length(bc.CODE) - c.LEN) ) "LOT",
        SubStr(bc.CODE, c.A + c.GTIN_LEN + c.B + A_DATE_LEN + c.C + (Length(bc.CODE) - c.LEN) + c.D + 1, TOTAL_LEN) "TOTAL"
From    bc 
Inner Join cols c ON(1 = 1)
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
 ID GTIN               A_DATE       LOT           TOTAL                                     
--- ------------------ ------------ ------------- --------
  1 18777777777777     241129       L3333333      02                                        
  2 18123444567890     240703       L1234         01                                        
  3 18000999888777     241231       L1122334455   03        */
```

NOTE: This is done with just SQL and it could be used without the function that you asked for. If you need the function to get your things working just apply the same logic of barcode pattern and structure or use the above as a cursor or select into within the function.
Pattern used:

```sql
/*
    A GTIN           B  A_DATE  C LOT      D   TOTAL
-- 01 18777777777777 15 241129 10 L3333333 F90 02
-- -- -------------- -- ------ -- -------- --- --
   12 3            1 11 1    2 22 2      3 333 33
                   6 78 9    4 56 7      4 567 89
-- -- -------------- -- ------ -- -------- --- --
    2             14  2      6  2        x   3  2  */
```

```sql
A      columns 1 to 2   length 2    
GTIN   columns 3 to 16  length 14    
B      columns 17 to 18 length 2    
A_DATE columns 19 to 24 length 6    
C      columns 25 to 26 length 2    
LOT    columns 27 to unknown length unknown     
D      columns here 35 to 37 (but depending on LOT length) length 3    
TOTAL  columns here 38 to 39 (but depending on LOT length) length 2
```

FUNCTION (if needed)

```sql
create or replace Function GetFromBarCode(p_code VarChar2, p_what VarChar2) RETURN VarChar2 IS
BEGIN
    Declare
        Cursor cols IS
              Select    2 "A", 
                        Max(Case When CODE = '01' Then To_Number(A_SIZE) End) "GTIN_LEN",
                        2 "B",
                        Max(Case When CODE = '15' Then To_Number(A_SIZE) End) "A_DATE_LEN",
                        2 "C",
                        Max(Case When CODE = '10' Then 0 End) "LOT_LEN",
                        3 "D",
                        Max(Case When CODE = '90' Then To_Number(A_SIZE) End) "TOTAL_LEN",
                        --
                        Max(Case When CODE = '01' Then To_Number(A_SIZE) End) + 
                        Max(Case When CODE = '15' Then To_Number(A_SIZE) End) + 
                        Max(Case When CODE = '90' Then To_Number(A_SIZE) End) + 9 "LEN"
                From    barcode_settings;
      colSet  cols%ROWTYPE;
      mRet    VarChar2(32) := 'n/a';
    Begin 
      OPEN cols;
      FETCH cols Into colSet;
      CLOSE cols;
      If p_what = '01' Then
          mRet := SubStr(p_code, colSet.A + 1, colSet.GTIN_LEN);
      ElsIf p_what = '15' Then
          mRet := Substr(p_code, colSet.A + colSet.GTIN_LEN + colSet.B + 1, colSet.A_DATE_LEN);
      ElsIf p_what = '10' Then 
          mRet := SubStr(p_code, colSet.A + colSet.GTIN_LEN + colSet.B + colSet.A_DATE_LEN + colSet.C + 1, (Length(p_code) - colSet.LEN ) );
      Elsif p_what = '90' Then
          mRet := SubStr(p_code, colSet.A + colSet.GTIN_LEN + colSet.B + colSet.A_DATE_LEN + colSet.C + (Length(p_code) - colSet.LEN) + colSet.D + 1, colSet.TOTAL_LEN);
      End If;
      Return mRet;
    End;
END GetFromBarCode;
```

```sql
--    T e s t :
Select  GetFromBarCode('01187777777777771524112910L3333333F9002', '01') "GTIN",
        GetFromBarCode('01187777777777771524112910L3333333F9002', '15') "A_DATE",
        GetFromBarCode('01187777777777771524112910L3333333F9002', '10') "LOT",
        GetFromBarCode('01187777777777771524112910L3333333F9002', '90') "TOTAL"
From Dual;
/*    R e s u l t :
--  GTIN               A_DATE       LOT           TOTAL                                     
--  ------------------ ------------ ------------- --------
--  18777777777777     241129         L3333333      02      */
```